# Disable remote debugging on WebView Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

How do i disable remote debugging on Android 4.4 KitKat? I have a hybrid app and for security reasons i do not want my users to see the content of the web pages. Setting the `static` method `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` to `false` does not seem to work. Also, the remote debugging seems to be enabled by default in my application even though in the [official API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled%28boolean%29) it states that is disabled by default.

**EDIT**
The tests are being performed in an emulator with Android 4.4 (since i do not have available a device with 4.4) on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebView in a user-debug build will always allow debugging of a WebView.

The WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true / false) will affect whether you can debug WebViews on user builds.

Comment: Can you provide any source (preferably official) about this? Thanks!

Comment: I work on the Chrome team, will make a note to update the DevTools documentation.

Comment: Since also @Kinlan mentioned it, i think i can accept your answer. Don't forget to update the documentation since i believe this is an important detail. Thanks again!

Comment: It is documented here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#configure-webview

Answer (score 2):

For me this code snippet works well for Android 4.4 (Nexus 7)

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if ( 0 != ( getApplcationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) ) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the above code but no luck. The problem is that by setting `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false);` i still can inspect the web contents in my app's WebView using the Google Chrome browser in my PC.

Comment: I've tested it on Nexus 7 with Android 4.4. Even calling WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false) does not show the process on the chrome://inspect page. How do you start debugging via chrome://inspect or some other way?

Comment: Since i do not have a device with 4.4, i can only test it on an emulator with 4.4 Android version. Maybe it is just happening on emulator but i cannot verify it.

Comment: I can clearly see the process in the chrome://inspect page and open it using a 4.4 emulator.

Comment: Confirmed - WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false) does also not work for me in the emulator - but maybe that's done by design ;-)

Comment: I will test the application on a 4.4 device (the hard part is to find one:)). When i confirm it i will accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to note.  If you are running emulator or a user-debug build then you can always get access to app via chrome://inspect

Comment: @Kinlan Can you provide the source about this (preferably official)? I thought that only the method `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` is responsible whether the WebView can be inspected through chrome://inspect.

Comment: @Kinlan Ok, i just saw that you work on the Google Chrome Team from your profile. As Gaunt Face mentioned can you please inform to update the documents for this behaviour? I do not think it is mentioned anywhere for now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean about the userdebug builds? the code snippet that @gauntface provided is documented here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#configure-webview